# Trying to preserve this original array fails here

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have this code below

```
resultOfAllScenarios=[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]]]
arr = resultOfAllScenarios
arr.each do |value|
  value.delete_if { |x|x.sum>3 }
end

p resultOfAllScenarios
```

Output

```
[[[1, 2]], [[1, 2]], [[1, 2]]]
```

I am copying `resultOfAllScenarios` into `arr` but still original array is mutated. So I did clone the array as shown below

```
resultOfAllScenarios=[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]]]
arr = resultOfAllScenarios.clone
arr.each do |value|
  value.delete_if { |x|x.sum>3 }
end

p resultOfAllScenarios
```

Output

```
[[[1, 2]], [[1, 2]], [[1, 2]]]
```

But still the original array get mutated. It seems like it's not cloning the inner array. What should I do to preserve the original array? Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs:

> The array is changed instantly every time the block is called, not
>   after the iteration is over.

With that, I can assume that the original array is always going to be modified. Check that after using `clone`, every element in the receiver end up being the same:

```
foo = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
p foo.map(&:object_id)
# [70238411027480, 70238411027460, 70238411027440]
bar = foo.clone
p bar.map(&:object_id)
# [70238411027480, 70238411027460, 70238411027440]
```

So, when you use `delete_if` you're modifying those objects, no matter if you cloned them.

*What should I do to preserve the original array?* Maybe you can just use `reject` to avoid mutating the object with no work extra:

```
resultOfAllScenarios=[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]]]
arr = resultOfAllScenarios.map do |value|
  value.reject { |x|x.sum>3 }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
arr = resultOfAllScenarios
```

You're basically referencing the memory of the array rather than its copy. Do `clone` instead:

```
arr = resultOfAllScenarios.map(&:clone)
```

What's happening here?:

```
arr = resultOfAllScenarios
pp resultOfAllScenarios.map(&:object_id) 
#=> [70173532995400, 70173532994980, 70173532994220]
pp arr.map(&:object_id)
#=> [70173532995400, 70173532994980, 70173532994220]
```

But when you `clone` the subarrays:

```
arr = resultOfAllScenarios.map(&:clone)

pp resultOfAllScenarios.map(&:object_id) 
#=> [70154004258860, 70154004274800, 70154004272760]

pp arr.map(&:object_id) 
#=> [70154004271580, 70154004271240, 70154004271120]
```

So, the `arr` now has references to new objects cloned from the `resultOfAllScenarios` in the latter example.

Comment: `dup` is having the same problem.

Comment: I was using `clone` in my example, Did you not see that?

Comment: @Rajagopalan - `dup` does not copy singleton or frozen objects, the `clone` does. Also, the individual subarrays are not being copied is the issue.

Comment: I am saying clone and dup has the same problem. I think Sebastian has gotten the problem. Going to check out that solution.

Comment: Oh I think I am understanding what you are saying, let me check.

Comment: YOur solution only works for this array but this example is the sample of what I have, I have many inner arrays. So it's not working for that.

Comment: I only answered based on the facts provided in the question.

Comment: I understand, but my array is very bigger and have many inner arrays, that's what I gave the sample here, that's what I can do also.